# What is the Equivilent of Screen.MonitorCount in an HD Firemonkey Application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I'm using XE4 and trying to determine how many monitors are attached in an HD Firemonkey application. In a VCL application you get this information from Screen.MonitorCount. What is the Firemonkey equivalent?

Comment: You will find all the necessary information in this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242998/how-to-show-a-firemonkey-form-on-second-monitor). In short, you will have to write platform specific code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one, as far as I can tell.There's a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9242998/62576) that discusses this being something you'll have to code yourself that's platform-specific, and the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Handling_the_Screen) clearly says that multiple screen support is for Windows only (**emphasis mine**):

> A global variable of type TScreen called Screen is created when you create a project. Screen encapsulates the state of the screen on which your application is running. Common tasks performed by Screen include specifying:
>
> - The look of the cursor.
> - The size of the window in which your application is running.
> - A list of fonts available to the screen device.
> - Multiple screen behavior **(Windows only)**.
>
> If your **Windows application** runs on multiple monitors, Screen maintains a list of monitors and their dimensions so that you can effectively manage the layout of your user interface.