# How to center Form on second monitor?

Tags: delphi, vcl, multiple-monitors, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm showing a Form on the second monitor (using [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966383/13342579)) and need it to appear centered.

Here is my last attempt, but without success. How can I achieve it?

```
    MonitorForm.Left := (mInfo.rcWork.Width - MonitorForm.Width)  div 2;
    MonitorForm.Top := (mInfo.rcWork.Height - MonitorForm.Height) div 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the monitor's position (Left/Top) in the overall desktop size into account:

```
MonitorForm.Left := mInfo.rcWork.Left + (mInfo.rcWork.Width - MonitorForm.Width) div 2;
MonitorForm.Top := mInfo.rcWork.Top + (mInfo.rcWork.Height - MonitorForm.Height) div 2;
```